# httpclient api for java project

Tags: java, http

Where can i find and download the api to implement that piece of code? I searched it with google but i can't find it. The only one i found is this: http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi  but it's not that. Thank you.

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.Cookie;  
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpState;  
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;  
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;  

public class GetCookiePrintAndSetValue {  

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {  

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();  
    client.getParams().setParameter("j_username", "abc");  
    client.getParams().setParameter("j_password", "pqr");  

    GetMethod method = new GetMethod("http://localhost:8080/");  
    try{  
      client.executeMethod(method);  
      Cookie[] cookies = client.getState().getCookies();  
      for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {  
        Cookie cookie = cookies[i];  
        System.err.println(  
          "Cookie: " + cookie.getName() +  
          ", Value: " + cookie.getValue() +  
          ", IsPersistent?: " + cookie.isPersistent() +  
          ", Expiry Date: " + cookie.getExpiryDate() +  
          ", Comment: " + cookie.getComment());  
        }  
      client.executeMethod(method);  
    } catch(Exception e) {  
      System.err.println(e);  
    } finally {  
      method.releaseConnection();  
    }  
  }  
}
```

Comment: What version of Jakarta Http Client have you tried?

Comment: This code snippet is using an old version of the apache libraries.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [project page](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/):

> The Commons HttpClient project is now end of life, and is no longer being developed. It has been replaced by the [Apache HttpComponents project](http://hc.apache.org/) in its HttpClient and HttpCore modules, which offer better performance and more flexibility.

So, you probably do want [that page](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi).

If you want an older version, like 3.0, you can find it [in the archives](http://archive.apache.org/dist/httpcomponents/commons-httpclient/).

Also, I highly recommend learning to use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), since it will make handling dependencies in projects [much easier](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1).